# Call WC_Product to My Plugin Returns Null

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am creating custom export plugin. I want to use $product instance in my plugin to get product info like below

It works when I use wc_get_product() in the theme's function file. It doesn't work in the plugin file I created myself.

```
$product->get_id();
```

When i trying to get;

```
$product = wc_get_product( $post->ID );
```

It returns bool(false).

I tried

```
global $product
global $post
global $woocommerce
    $products = get_posts([
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'fields' => 'ids',
      ]);
```

But i can't get any.

Comment: Your question is still vague. Please add more details.

Comment: I updated question. I am creating a custom plugin. I need $product instance. It works when I use wc_get_product() in the theme's function file. It doesn't work in the plugin file I created myself.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If your file is not in the root directory of plugin, try using

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');
require_once("config-request.php");
```

in the above. I hope it fix. Root directory of plugin works same as functions.php but other sub directory will not.

Comment: require_once("config-request.php"); giving errors.

Comment: Sorry to mentioned that 'config-request.php' is to use the config setting of wordpress. You need to create in a new file.

<?php
$configpath = find_require('wp-config.php');

function find_require($file,$folder=null) {
    if ($folder === null) {$folder = dirname(__FILE__);}
    $path = $folder.'/'.$file;
    if (file_exists($path)) {require($path); return $folder;}
    else {
        $upfolder = find_require($file,dirname($folder));
        if ($upfolder != '') {return $upfolder;}
    }
}
?>

like this, I hope it work. It works on my side.

Comment: Warning: Use of undefined constant FILE - assumed 'FILE' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

Comment: Please change to this `dirname(__FILE__)`, it show PHP syntax warning. Since I didn't paste as code, it automatically remove the underscore in code.